# How to take Input using while in java for Contests

Tags: java, io

I am trying to solve [this "exponentiation" problem](http://poj.org/problem?id=1001).

Here is the code that I have written

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        BigDecimal R,f;// = new BigInteger();
        ArrayList <String> ans = new ArrayList <String> ();
        int n;
   /////  I dont know how to deal with it         
    while(  R = Input.nextBigDecimal(), n = Input.nextInt() )
    ////
    f = R.pow(n);
    f = f.stripTrailingZeros();
    String s = f.toPlainString();
    String answer = "";
    answer = s;

    if(s.charAt(0) == '0')
        s = s.substring(1);
    ans.add(answer);

    System.out.println(s);


    }

}
```

Now The question that I want to ask is that how would I take input until the end of file?
(I have solved such problems using c++  using while(cin >> v >> s) etc )  But I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanner class has also [hasNextBigDecimal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextBigDecimal%28%29) method, so you would like to do:

```
while ( Input.hasNextBigDecimal() ) {
    R = Input.nextBigDecimal();
    n = Input.nextInt();
    ... // processing
}
```

Scanner is slow for huge input files. I'm using BufferedReader if the line has well known format (for example two numbers separated by space):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
String parts[] = br.readLine().split( " " );
```

If you want to use java, you should learn also [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

And even better than `split` is to use `StringTokenizer`, it's quicker.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for you question is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Please enter the R and n values seperated by space");
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigDecimal R = null;
    BigDecimal f = null;// = new BigInteger();
    ArrayList<String> ans = new ArrayList<String>();
    int n = 0;

    R = (Input.nextBigDecimal());
    System.out.println("The value of R is " + R);
    n = Input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The value of n is " + n);

    f = R.pow(n);
    f = f.stripTrailingZeros();
    String s = f.toPlainString();
    String answer = "";
    answer = s;

    if (s.charAt(0) == '0') {
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    ans.add(answer);

    System.out.println(s);

}
```

Note: The above code does not check for the valid input.